# VBA Excel Userform Clear Range after vbYesNo

Tags: vba, excel, userform

The code below is intended to check if the cells in a given range are empty. If they are not, the user is asked if they want to save the contents of the range. If they select "No" the contents of the range is cleared.

```
 Dim answer As Integer

If Not WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Temp").Range("A1:D101")) = 0    Then
    answer = MsgBox("Save changes for this account?", vbYesNo)
 If answer = vbYes Then
   'do nothing
 Else
   Worksheets("Temp").Range("A1:D101").ClearContents
 End If
End If
```

For some reason the clear method just won't clear anything. I have tried first activating the sheet. First selecting the range. First selecting the sheet then selecting the range. Using ".Clear" instead of ".ClearContents". Adding an Else statement to the outer If statement. I've tried selecting a range of only filled cells. No matter what I've done, the contents of the range will stay there until I delete it manually. Everything else seems to work fine. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is missing from my code.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** Here is the code for the entire function:

```
Private Sub NameBox_Change()

Dim answer As Integer

If Not WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Temp").Range("A1:D101")) = 0 Then
    answer = MsgBox("Save changes for this account?", vbYesNo)
 If answer = vbYes Then
   'do nothing
 Else
   Worksheets("Temp").Range("A1:D101").ClearContents
 End If
End If

With Me

    Worksheets("Temp").Cells(1, 1).Value = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
    Worksheets("Temp").Cells(1, 2).Value = Worksheets("Users").Cells(.NameBox.ListIndex + 1, 1).Value
    Worksheets("Temp").Cells(1, 3).Value = Worksheets("Users").Cells(.NameBox.ListIndex + 1, 6).Value
    Worksheets("Temp").Cells(1, 4).Value = Worksheets("Users").Cells(.NameBox.ListIndex + 1, 7).Value


    ReadLabel.Caption = Worksheets("Temp").Cells(102, 3).Value
    SpentLabel.Caption = Worksheets("Temp").Cells(102, 4).Value
    ToSpendLabel.Caption = Worksheets("Temp").Cells(102, 3).Value - Worksheets("Temp").Cells(102, 4).Value

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anything special about this range? is it a part of a larger array formula?

Comment: If you debug, are you getting to the `ClearContents` line?

Comment: The values of the range are populated by the values of another sheet. I had and Auto Sum cell set up at one point but have since removed it. The debugger doesn't have any issues with my code and I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. This function is triggered when a the user selects a new name from a dropdown list. The original name was being cleared and then replaced by the new name. I just hadn't realized that the names had changed. Thanks for helping my look at this with fresh eyes. I will leave the question up in case someone finds my code useful.